# Detect if pointer is nil with Parse-Server

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

I am trying to detect if a pointer is actually in my database for a key "school_name". Normally, I can check if a key has a value by writing

```
if PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("school_name") == nil {

    // Do Something

}
```

If I run the same command for a key containing a pointer, it always comes out as nil.

I tried

```
if PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("school_name")?.pointerValue == nil

    // Do Something

}
```

But it always comes out to nil

I'm sure there is a value there because I can access it in other parts of the app on on the parse server dashboard. Am I doing it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out but thought that I would leave the post up for others.

I have to use:

```
if PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("school_name")?.objectId == nil

// Do Something

}
```